# Getting null data from a JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Essentially, this is the kind of data I want returned:

```
{
   "Top10BidAsks":[
      {
         "Bid":{
            "Price":10.0,
            "Size":2.0,
            "ExchangeID":"SMART",
            "timeStamp":0
         },
         "Ask":{
            "Price":12.0,
            "Size":2.0,
            "ExchangeID":"SMART",
            "timeStamp":0
         }
      },
      {
         "Bid":{
            "Price":0.0,
            "Size":0.0,
            "ExchangeID":"SMART",
            "timeStamp":0
         },
         "Ask":{
            "Price":13.0,
            "Size":12.0,
            "ExchangeID":"SMART",
            "timeStamp":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The {"Price":10.0,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0}, essentially represents a MarketData Object that I've created with those 4 fields.

The main function I'm calling is:

```
public MarketDataListLevel2 getMarketDataDepth() {
    try {
        MarketDataListLevel2 md = cs.getMarketDataDepth();
        log.info(md.toString());
        return md;
     }
     catch ( Exception e) {
        ....
     }
}
```

Where cs is just an interface that retrieves the JSON data from a site.

The MarketDataLevel2 object is:

```
public class MarketDataListLevel2 {

public static class MarketDataList {
    public MarketData[] a;
}

public MarketDataList[] listofmarketdatalists;

public MarketDataListLevel2(@JsonProperty("Top10BidAsks") MarketDataList[] listofmarketdatalists) {
    this.listofmarketdatalists = listofmarketdatalists;
}
```

I tried to make this object match the output I want (formatting wise), but apparently I might have a data structure error here, because I'm not getting the data I want returned.

When I run the first method that I listed:

```
MarketDataListLevel2 a = getDepthMarketData(coin);
```

When I debug this 'a' object, I see that each element in the listofmarketdatalists array is 'null'
 instead of containing an object with this format: {"Bid":{"Price":10.0,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},
  "Ask":{"Price":12.0,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0}}.

Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create correct POJO classes which represent your JSON. See below example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Root root = mapper.readValue(json, Root.class);
        System.out.println(root.getTop10());
    }
}

class Root {

    @JsonProperty("Top10BidAsks")
    private List<MarketDataEntity> top10;

    public List<MarketDataEntity> getTop10() {
        return top10;
    }

    public void setTop10(List<MarketDataEntity> top10) {
        this.top10 = top10;
    }
}

class MarketDataEntity {

    private Map<String, MarketData> datas = new HashMap<String, MarketData>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setMarketData(String key, MarketData data) {
        datas.put(key, data);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return datas.toString();
    }
}

class MarketData {

    @JsonProperty("Price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @JsonProperty("Size")
    private BigDecimal size;

    @JsonProperty("ExchangeID")
    private String exchangeId;

    private int timeStamp;

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(BigDecimal size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getExchangeId() {
        return exchangeId;
    }

    public void setExchangeId(String exchangeId) {
        this.exchangeId = exchangeId;
    }

    public int getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(int timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MarketData [price=" + price + ", size=" + size + ", exchangeId=" + exchangeId + ", timeStamp=" + timeStamp + "]";
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
[{Bid=MarketData [price=10.0, size=2.0, exchangeId=SMART, timeStamp=0], Ask=MarketData [price=12.0, size=2.0, exchangeId=SMART, timeStamp=0]}, {Bid=MarketData [price=0.0, size=0.0, exchangeId=SMART, timeStamp=0], Ask=MarketData [price=13.0, size=12.0, exchangeId=SMART, timeStamp=0]}]
```